# Stick pyramids on a square

Tags: 3d, texture, cinema4d

I'm quite new to cinema 4D. I want to make a square with [this texture](http://fungadgets.dk/3482-4172-large/iphone-5-cover-med-nitter-i-sort.jpg) on.

[image]

I've tried to make a pyramid and to use the cloner tool, but.. just can't make it work.

Anyone who can tell me how it's done? Or maybe can give me a nice tutorial?

Tried making a cloned pyramid and placed them (roate and moove) so it looks like i want it, but the cube isn't a part of that.. and dont even know if I placed them the right way..

Thx

[image: Screenshot of projekt]

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to GD! It would be most helpful if you could add some screenshots and show us what you have tried and where exactly you get stuck. This saves everybody time, and makes it more likely that you will get helpful answers. This is not really a tutorial-site as such; we expect to see some effort. You might not get a tutorial but rather detailed pointers are more likely.

Comment: Sure.. it's done now :-)